# Radio Button and Dropdown Validation

Tags: jquery

What I am trying to do is, on clicking the save button, if a user has chosen any Missing Radio Button but have not chosen a drop down option, then an alert message needs to show.

I tried 2 approaches. First is this way

```
if ($(".missing input[type:radio]:checked").length > 0 && $(".reason").val() == "")
  { 
   alert("You have not selected a reason from the drop down list of the Missing section.");
  return false;
  }
```

Second method -- by identifying the text in the textarea. If it contains ~CM~~ then show an alert

```
if ("ta:contains(~CM~~).length>0")
{
alert("Missing radio has been selected but nothing in the drop down has been selected");
}
```

I have commented out the code in the fiddle and feel to use any method.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/19eggs/gFvT7/7/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it's not a good approach to use `<table>` to design your site, because the crawler won't able to get any info from your web.. Even for this issue, I added dummy class to your `<tr>` that has those radio buttons..

Change your 2 approaches into this:

```
//for checking the combobox
$('.selection').each(function(){
    if($(this).find(".missing input").attr("checked") == "checked" && $(this).find(".reason").val() == ""){
        alert("You have not selected a reason from the drop down list of the Missing section.");
    }
});
//for checking the textarea
$('.selection').each(function(){
    if($(this).find(".missing input").attr("checked") == "checked" && $(this).find("textarea").val() == ""){
        alert("You have not type anything in the textarea.");
    }
});
```

Check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gFvT7/8/).

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I can't add anything to the tr. Could you kindly tell me why my second code ( :contains) doesn't work. It is meant to check if the textarea has ~CM~~ If it has then alert.

Comment: I don't exactly why, but the similar approach is like this: `if(ta.indexOf("~CM~~")>0)`